# Employees Provident Fund

Tags: india, provident-fund

My age is 35 years. At The age of 24 I Worked in a firm on which provident fund was applied in Jalandhar Punjab in 2007.

Three years after I left the job due to depression in 2011. During this period rs. 10000 was deducted as Provident Fund from my salary. Due to depression, I could not withdraw my provident fund.

Eight years have passed till now. I want to know

1. Can I withdraw my provident fund now . If not why? I want to know what has happened to my account. I want to know if it has been distributed othetwise. Is it possible. As per EPF rules if an employee does not withdraw EPF 36 months after closing it it becomes inoperative. What is an inoperative account . what happens to it. As per internet when an employee after retirement at the age of 55 years do not withdraw EPF within 36 months it becomes inoperative . And after 7 years of its becoming inoperative it is transferred to senior citizen welfare fund. Means after 10 years of closing an EPF account is transferred to senior citizen welfare fund. And that too at the age of 55. Can such case happen to my account ,because my age is only 35 and only 8 years have passed after its closing. I want to know - 1. What has happened to my account.
2. If my fund has been distributed otherwise I have not been informed about it through any notice. Is it not illegal to do so with someone's account? Is not it the duty of the department to inform an employee before doing anything to his of account. Please clarify it.

Comment: Did you ask your former employer?  Did they give you an account number, username, etc so that you can check yourself?

Comment: I have not asked anything about it to my former employer.But I have proof of it.When I was working there two EPF cards were made and generated to me as proof of my registration with the EPF department two times. I have these two EPF cards as proof of my provident fund investment with the department.But on one EPF card generated to me by the department insurance number 9700842 has been written

Comment: What stop you from going to the bureaucrat office to confirmed everything?

Comment: try this https://unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in/memberinterface/

Answer (score 1):

The deductions are credited to 2 different account. EPF, that can be withdrawn, FPF max of rs 1250 per month. This portion is used to give you pension after retirement.

Your employer or PF office can help

Comment: What is FPF? Are you talking about EPS?

Comment: @CanuteS from the deductions there are 2 parts.  FPF is a family pension scheme run by Govt, defined benefits. The deduction are mandatory by law subject to conditions, i.e. number of employees and basic salary. After retirement one will get life long pension